# How do I traverse an XML tree in the right order (python)

Tags: python, xml, traversal

My tree is like this (first number is the level, second number is the index on that level):

```
11  
12  
13  
  21  
  22  
    31
    32   
    33
```

when I iterate over the tree I get this:

```
----11
----12
------21
--------31
--------32
--------33
------22
----13
```

Here is the code :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def perf_func(elem, func, level=0):
    func(elem,level)
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        perf_func(child, func, level+1)

def print_level(elem,level):
        print '-'*level+elem.tag

with open('Map.xml', 'rt') as f:
tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
perf_func(Tree, print_level)
```

Update: here is the read data that I am working with. I am trying to print only the text (PlainText not null) and the formatting for this text

```
<ap:OneTopic>
    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
        <ap:SubTopics>
            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="Tyvwk/tRCUGYSZe8Gm1hKw==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                <ap:SubTopics>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="g1+iDTazMUaJf6HWSIz69Q==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:SubTopics>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="KTsoZbCe/Uq0IgYi9JVRvQ==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="1123" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                        </ap:SubTopics>
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                            <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                        </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="1121" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="QzZ2AAYYS0a5aE+v2z9dkA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="1122" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                </ap:SubTopics>
                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                    <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="11" ReadOnly="false">
                    <ap:Font/>
                </ap:Text>
            </ap:Topic>
            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="7qQAOqWlmkKn4t4Z2DMd5A==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                <ap:SubTopics>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="ro5nEHjge0qcWHXXO7/8sA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="1221" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="R5CK83KQTEquBBqivm8Lmg==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:SubTopics>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="xGn0UoleIU681h90xtm7oQ==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="12223" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                        </ap:SubTopics>
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                            <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                        </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="1222" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                </ap:SubTopics>
                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                    <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="12" ReadOnly="false">
                    <ap:Font/>
                </ap:Text>
            </ap:Topic>
            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="jH0FY5i1/Uu7cPCFcFgoCQ==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                <ap:SubTopics>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="TX7JXfIvn0WOpoqvUCKzUA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="21" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                    <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="mOwoPsJM20SjK2j7RwqNow==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:SubTopics>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="/BWUGWt6mE6vUXJZDRxskw==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="31" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="sqYG4DtARUq2NplBb7atEg==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="32" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="QfxZRuomGk6kllnrvrT25w==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="33" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                        </ap:SubTopics>
                        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                            <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                        </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                        <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="22" ReadOnly="false">
                            <ap:Font/>
                        </ap:Text>
                    </ap:Topic>
                </ap:SubTopics>
                <ap:OneBoundary>
                    <ap:Boundary Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="paP2GTbrYEuUuE6rusovoA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                        <ap:BoundaryViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                        <ap:BoundaryShape BoundaryShape="urn:mindjet:SummaryArc" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                        <ap:OneSummaryTopic>
                            <ap:Topic Dirty="0000000000000001" OId="QjLln9LrlUSlfS87gzyGxA==" Gen="0000000000000000">
                                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0"/>
                                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="Call out topic" ReadOnly="false">
                                    <ap:Font/>
                                </ap:Text>
                            </ap:Topic>
                        </ap:OneSummaryTopic>
                    </ap:Boundary>
                </ap:OneBoundary>
                <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
                    <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
                </ap:TopicViewGroup>
                <ap:Text Dirty="0000000000000001" PlainText="13" ReadOnly="false">
                    <ap:Font Color="ffff0000"/>
                </ap:Text>
            </ap:Topic>
        </ap:SubTopics>
        <ap:TopicViewGroup ViewIndex="0">
            <ap:Collapsed Collapsed="false" Dirty="0000000000000001"/>
        </ap:TopicViewGroup>
        <ap:SubTopicsShape SubTopicsVerticalAlignment="urn:mindjet:Middle" Dirty="0000000000000000"/>
    </ap:Topic>
</ap:OneTopic>
```

With the code quoted above I get this (some "if" conditions were removed from the quoted code)

```
--------1123
------1121
------1122
----11
------1221
--------12223
------1222
----12
------21
--------31
--------32
--------33
------22
--------Call out topic
----13
-----ffff0000
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual XML source?

Comment: Quite complicated, I am actually locating a section of the XML tree with tree.find and then I iterate over that section. The XML file is not standard and it has a lot attributes that are irrelevant for the topic.

Comment: Then maybe you can produce a sample that demonstrates the problem when processed with the code in your question?

Comment: I am working on it

Comment: OK I posted the data... see my update

Comment: Anyway you could make a [mcve] of that XML that demonstrates the same problem?

Comment: The issue is with the structure of the file. This is a mind map and I expected the structure of the file to follow the structure of the mind map but as you can see in the sample data, it first lists the children and then the text for that node which in turn produces the strange result. What I am doing is OK, it is just that the file is oddly structured